# Differentiation of a real-valued function which depends on a vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am unable to derive the differentiation of this function $f$:
$$f(\rho(\mathbf{r}),\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r}))= \rho(\mathbf{r}) \times E(\rho(\mathbf{r}),\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r})) $$

Here $\mathbf{g}=\mathbf{\nabla} \rho$, $\mathbf{r}$ is the position vector and we use $g$ to mean $||\mathbf{g}||$.

The paper says:
$$\frac{df}{d\rho}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} - \mathbf{\nabla}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{g}}=E+\rho\frac{\partial E}{\partial \rho}-g\frac{\partial E}{\partial g}-\rho g\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial g \partial \rho}-\frac{\rho}{g}\frac{\partial E}{\partial g}\nabla^2\rho+\frac{\rho}{g^2}\frac{\partial E}{\partial g}\mathbf{g}\mathbf{\nabla}g - \frac{\rho}{g}\frac{\partial^2 E} {\partial g^2}\mathbf{g}\mathbf{\nabla}g$$

How I tried (equation corrected after Nikos M. pointed out a mistake):
$$\frac{df}{d\rho}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{g}}\cdot\frac{d \mathbf{g}}{d \rho}$$ I am unable to get the second term $- \mathbf{\nabla}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{g}}$ and can't continue the further simplification.

The paper can be viewed [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0104171v1.pdf). This calculation is in page 2 of the paper in equation (2).

Comment: well the second term should relate to $\frac{\partial \vec{g}}{\partial \rho}$ and $\vec{g}=\vec{\nabla} \rho$, but i think something is missing

Comment: it may help if you include the rest notes on that paper as i see it sth is missing

Comment: plus it should be $\frac{df}{d\rho}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{g}}\cdot\frac{d \mathbf{g}}{d \rho}$ as it is a [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative)

Comment: Thanks @NikosM. The link to the paper is now added to the question.